# How to hint base class function that returns an instance of derived class it is called from?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

I want to hint that for B-instance `.duplicate_itself(`) returns B-instance, not A-instance.

```
class A:
    def duplicate_itself(self) -> 'WHAT SHOULD I WRITE HERE?'
        return self.__class__()         

class B(A):
    pass
```

BTW I am using PyCharm, so feel free to write an answer if you know some PyCharm specific solution

Comment: How is PyCharm relevant to the question?

Comment: I'm not sure but as type hinting is static, is it possible?

Comment: @Aran-Fey, i've added pycharm related note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by attaching a [`TypeVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar) to `self`:

```
T = typing.TypeVar('T')

class A:
    def duplicate_itself(self: T) -> T:
        return self.__class__()
```

Comment: It was hard for me, to understand [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TypeVar). But now everything clear! Will read it again.

Comment: @AlexanderChzhen -- if you want more detailed docs, you may want to check out [mypy's](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generics.html#generic-methods-and-generic-self) -- it generally does a more thorough job of explaining PEP 484 semantics. Warning: while most of the docs apply to both mypy and PyCharm (or any PEP 484 compliant typechecker), you might run into one or two sections which are mypy-specific or which mypy implements differently from Pycharm.